# Querying dBase file in C#

Tags: c#, dbase

My problem specifically is I can't filter by a Date field.

Here is my code:

```
string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\Tools;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";

using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connstr))
{
    string sql = "select USERNUMBER,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME, LASTACCESS from EMP WHERE TERMINATED=\"Y\" AND [LASTACCESS]<\"2001/10/20\"";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

    con.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

It works fine if I omit the date field.  I just can't figure out what the format is.  If I look at the table with a dbf viewer utility the LASTACCESS field is in dd.mm.yyyy (with the periods as separators, but I don't know if that is just a behavior of the utility).

If I omit the forward slashes from the date field, it works but returns zero records (even though I know there are).

Comment: If the format is `dd.mm.yyyy` why are you doing `[LASTACCESS]<\"2001/10/20\"` which is `yyyy.mm.dd`? Shouldn't it be `[LASTACCESS]<\"2001/10/20\"`?

Comment: If it is a string then change the format in your attempt to fit that returned by the tool (dd.mm.yyyy). Otherwise you might also try using a parameterized query and pass in a `DateTime` instance for the value.

Comment: @Adosi That was just one of my attempts. I used every type of formatting imaginable.  Using a parameterized query ended up being the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and forget date time hell

```
string sql = "select USERNUMBER,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME, LASTACCESS from EMP WHERE TERMINATED=\"Y\" AND [LASTACCESS]<@StartDate";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", new DateTime(2001, 10, 20));
```

Just use parameters and forget about formatting them yourself .

The framework is here to help you and provide solutions already tested and working like a charm